# Finding 2D vector AQ with addition/ subtraction

Tags: vectors

I was doing some 2D vector practices and came across a problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMUT6.png *(I'm not yet allowed to embed a picture so here's a link)*

I was asked to find the vector `AQ` and my answer was

`AB + AC`

`= b - a - c + a`

`= b - c`

But the answer is `- a + 1/2(b) + 1/2 c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\vec{AQ}=\frac{1}{2}(\vec{AB}+\vec{AC})=\frac{1}{2}[(\vec b -\vec a)+(\vec c-\vec a)]=\frac{1}{2}\vec b+\frac{1}{2}\vec c-\vec a$$

Note that $\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}$ in the diagonal of the parallelogram with sides $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$. $\vec{AQ}$ is just half of that.

Comment: Thanks! You're very helpful.